# SOQL - Querying for a list of opportunities the current user is following

Tags: salesforce, soql

My app is supposed to display all Salesforce Opportunities which current user follows. Do you know If it is possible to query theme using SOQL. I have been trying something like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name 
 FROM Opportunity 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT ParentId FROM FeedSubscriptionsForEntity WHERE SubscriberId = '#id')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution to this problem.

Second select should query from EntitySubscription table not FeedSubscriptionsForEntity property. Stupid mistake.

```
SELECT Id, Name 
 FROM Opportunity 
  WHERE Id IN (SELECT ParentId FROM EntitySubscription WHERE SubscriberId = '#id')
```